# How to count LaTeX page only with even numbers? (2,4,6,8...)

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have some problem to set my counter page with a step equal to 2.

I tried to use the command:`addcounter{page}{2}`
But it only increases the current page by 2.

I also tried to create a new counter, but I am not very confident with LaTeX enviromnent, just a new user.

Thank you for all possibles answear!

Packages I use in the script:

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}


\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}) }
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont
```

Comment: Please add a [mre] so we can see you documentclass and relevant packages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of actually changing the page numbering, you could change how the page number is displayed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyfoot[c]{\number\numexpr2*\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}


\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}) }
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

\duckument

\end{document}
```

Comment: This method works but, in the Table of Contents TOC, numbers of every chapter are wrong

Comment: @giuseppeantoniomotisi The incomplete code fragment in your question does not have a toc

Comment: I usually include toc in title.tex, you are right. But it doesn't work as it does, do you know how to set the counter page for all document environments?